# Show Add New button for the last empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to show "Add New" button for the last object that is empty.
The code that I'm using is"

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent () => {
    const data = [{
    0: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Data 1"
    },
    1: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Data 2"
    },
    2: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Data 3"
    },
    3: {
        id: 4,
        name: "Data 4"
    },
    4: {}
}];

return (
    {data.length - 1 ? (
    <Button>Add New</Button>
    ) : (
    <Button>Edit</Button>
    )}
);
}
```

I checked if is the last object and show "Add New" else "Show Edit", but, every time is displaying "Edit" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just copied the `data` from `console.log` and paste it in to your code which is wrong and you need to make these changes:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Data 1",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Data 2",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Data 3",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Data 4",
    },
    {},
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {data?.map((item, index) => {
        if ((index !== data?.length) && item.id) {
          return <Button>Edit</Button>;
        } else if(!item.id){
          return <Button>Add New</Button>;
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` on `data` to identify if object is valid (and then show `Add new` or `Edit` button) like:

```js
const data = [{
        0: {
            id: 1,
            name: "Data 1"
        },
        1: {
            id: 2,
            name: "Data 2"
        },
        2: {
            id: 3,
            name: "Data 3"
        },
        3: {
            id: 4,
            name: "Data 4"
        },
        4: {}
    }];
    let datalength = Object.values(data[0]).length;
    if(Object.values(data[0])[datalength - 1].id) {
       // valid object
    }
    else {
      // invalid object
    }
```

Comment: hi Giovanni. Yeah, comes in my mind to check by ID, but those data can come from context, and this last object can be filled with data, and it can have the ID, for that reason I need to check only for last object.

Comment: Ciao @alar, if you need to check only last object you could use `Object.values(data[0])[datalength - 1].id` where `datalength` is the array length. Right?